# SQL GROUP BY quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Using Microsot's SQL server I want to show a list of each costumer and they spends by year and quarter. So, I have the next code:

```
    SELECT CompanyName AS 'Customer', YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Year' ,
    Quarter1 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
    WHEN 1 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
    ELSE 0
    END,
    Quarter2 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
    WHEN 2 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
    ELSE 0
    END,
    Quarter3 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
    WHEN 3 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
    ELSE 0
    END,
    Quarter4 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
    WHEN 4 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
    ELSE 0
    END
 FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
 LEFT JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
 GROUP BY CompanyName, YEAR(OrderDate), DATEPART(q, OrderDate)
```

But it shows a SINGLE ROW per quarter, for example:

```
Customer    Year    Quarter1    Quarter2    Quarter3   Quarter4
--------    ----    --------    --------    --------   --------
John Smith  1997         127           0           0          0
John Smith  1997           0         254           0          0
John Smith  1997           0           0         547          0
John Smith  1997           0           0           0        155
```

What I want is a single row per cutomer, in this case:

```
Customer    Year    Quarter1    Quarter2    Quarter3   Quarter4
--------    ----    --------    --------    --------   -------- 
John Smith  1997         127         254         547        155
```

Any advice?

Thx.

Comment: So what is your expected output

Comment: One line per cutomer

Comment: maybe just calculate sum() for when statement like this `sum(WHEN 1 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
    ELSE 0
    END)`

Comment: Dont group by with DATEPART(q, OrderDate), try this query removing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your query and group it by customer and year. something like this...

```
SELECT Customer,Year,SUM(Quarter1) AS Quarter1,SUM(Quarter2) AS Quarter2,SUM(Quarter3) AS Quarter3,SUM(Quarter4) AS Quarter4
FROM
(
    SELECT CompanyName AS 'Customer', YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Year' ,
    Quarter1 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
    WHEN 1 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
    ELSE 0
    END,
    Quarter2 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
    WHEN 2 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
    ELSE 0
    END,
    Quarter3 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
    WHEN 3 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
    ELSE 0
    END,
    Quarter4 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
    WHEN 4 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
    ELSE 0
    END
 FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
 LEFT JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
 GROUP BY CompanyName, YEAR(OrderDate), DATEPART(q, OrderDate)
 )C
 GROUP BY CompanyName,Year
```

Comment: Like a globe. Thank you very much, but Why doest that ")C" stands for?

Comment: Its an alias for the inner derived table

Answer (score 2):

use Common Table Expression [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
  ;with cte1 as
    (
     SELECT CompanyName AS 'Customer', YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Year' ,
        Quarter1 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
        WHEN 1 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
        ELSE 0
        END,
        Quarter2 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
        WHEN 2 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
        ELSE 0
        END,
        Quarter3 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
        WHEN 3 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
        ELSE 0
        END,
        Quarter4 = CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
        WHEN 4 THEN SUM((UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount))
        ELSE 0
        END
     FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
     LEFT JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
     GROUP BY CompanyName, YEAR(OrderDate), DATEPART(q, OrderDate)
    )
select Customer,max(Year), max(Quarter1),max(Quarter2),max(Quarter3),max(Quarter4) from cte1 group by Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

simple remove the group by quarter part and wrap the sum around your cases:

```
SELECT CompanyName AS 'Customer', YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Year' 
 , Quarter1 = SUM(CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
                    WHEN 1 THEN (UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount)
                    ELSE 0
                  END),
 , Quarter2 = SUM(CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
                    WHEN 2 THEN (UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount)
                    ELSE 0
                  END),
 , Quarter3 = SUM(CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
                    WHEN 3 THEN (UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount)
                    ELSE 0
                  END),
 , Quarter4 = SUM(CASE(DATEPART(q, Orders.OrderDate))
                    WHEN 4 THEN (UnitPrice*Quantity)*(1-Discount)
                    ELSE 0
                  END),
 FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
 LEFT JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
 GROUP BY CompanyName, YEAR(OrderDate)
```